# Word or phrase for a person who is impatient and likes studying new things by example?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

Is there a specific word or phrase to describe a person who is

- impatient learning new things
- dislikes reading lengthy passages
- always likes learning by example plus doing experiments in parallel?

Note that I am the person in question.

Comment: “An eager but hotheaded student”, perhaps? I can think of no word that carries all the meanings you're looking for.

Comment: Perhaps an [autodidact](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autodidacticism)?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch: Perhaps an impatient, learn-by-example autodidact?

Comment: @StiffJokes An autodidact will learn it their way, regardless of how the teacher (or the material) is structured. When impatient, do you read ahead?

Comment: Hi, @StiffJokes, I've made some edits to hopefully make your question read a little more clearly, but feel free to edit again or revert my changes if I lost any of your original meaning! I am not sure what you mean by "reading by example".

Comment: It is called the pathology of being a normal human.

Comment: Could it be 'impetuous'?

Comment: Perhaps ADHD? (No offense intended!)

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you are describing some of the attributes of one of the learning styles known as the 
[*kinesthetic or tactile learner.*](http://www.alnmag.com/articles/2011/06/training-kinesthetic-learner)

Answer (score 1):

Without any reference to back me up, I believe this word fits all the attributes you gave:

an **impatient experimenter**

Answer (score 0):

It's not exactly what you're looking for, but how about:

> Maverick:
>
> an unorthodox or independent-minded person:

Comment: I am so sorry, it is not suitable I think. :-)

Comment: No, I didn't think so. Maverick is someone who does things on their own - in their own way - probably not learning from someone else.